# How to apply styling to Bing Map tiles to hide road numbers?

Tags: leaflet, bing-maps

I am using Leaflet + Bing map to load the map in my application. I have customized bing map using the following way,

```
'Default': L.bingLayer({
            key: <BING_MAP_KEY>,
            imagerySet: 'RoadOnDemand',
            culture: 'en-US',
            style: 'pt|v:0_rl|v:0_me|lbc:a0a1a1;loc:272727_rv|fc:383a3c;lbc:a0a1a1;loc:000505_wt|fc:383a3c;lbc:a0a1a1;loc:000505_ar|fc:474747_trs|fc:222527;lbc:a0a1a1;loc:000505;sc:0_g|lc:2f3133;srv:0'
        }),
```

But I am seeing a lot of highway numbers on my map in green color as below. It would be really great if someone could help me modify the styling to remove the icons from the map?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The technical name for "highway numbers in green" is **highway shields**. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_shield and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Custom_Highway_Shields.

Therefore, when looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/styling/map-style-sheet-entries , look for the word "shield". According to that and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/styling/map-style-sheet-entry-properties , the way to hide road/highway shields would be a string like

```
rs|lv:false
```

...appended at the end of your `style` string, separated by an underscore (as per the docs).

Comment: @rbrundritt I have already tried following styling properties ` rs|v:0 ` , `rs|lv:0` and `rs|lv:false`. But it did not make any change to the map. Still, the highway shield icons are visible.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm at a loss, then.

Comment: I have tried in 'Microsoft Map Style Editor' to customize the style. When I update the scale property to 0, it works in the editor. But I could not find any property for scale in documentation for WEB, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/styling/map-style-sheet-entry-properties#mapelement-properties

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following customization to hide the road numbers and its works fine!

```
'Default': L.bingLayer({
            key: <BING_MAP_KEY>,
            imagerySet: 'CanvasDark',
            culture: 'en-US',
            style: 'rs|fc:0087FFE3;ic:00FF300E;lbc:00FFFFFF;sc:00FFFFFF_ . . . '
        })
```

Thanks, @IvanSanchez for guiding me in to the right direction.